# How to create new branch off prior branch instead of current branch, and switch between that and current branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I am using a Microsoft Azure Devops site for source control of my winforms solution. As shown below, I have created a 6.0.0.0 branch off of the 5.24.1.0 branch in Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

I now want to keep my changes from the 6.0.0.0 branch and create 5.25.0.0 branch off of 5.24.1.0, but when I do this the result is a branch called 5.25.0.0 which is a combination of 5.24.1.0 and 6.0.0.0:

[image]

Is it possible to branch off 5.24.1.0 without any changes from 6.0.0.0 being included, and then to switch between 5.25.0.0 and 6.0.0.0 as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the starting point is correct.

Since you have not done any new commit on branches  5.24.1.0 and 6.0.0.0, your thrid new branch  5.25.0.0 is, for now, at the same starting commit: the one already referenced by the other two branches.

Start making commits, and you will see each branch will have their own HEAD label, independently of the others.

Comment: You were exactly right. Thanks! I committed 6.0.0.0 changes and now see that 5.25.0.0 is the same as 5.24.1.0 since I haven't made any changes in that branch yet. 6.0.0.0 has its own HEAD label though. Now when I switch between 5.25.0.0 and 6.0.0.0 I see the changes exactly as I was hoping to. Thanks a lot for the help.